# Reading SQL/PHP

Tags: php, sql, insert, str-replace

I'm trying to simply read and thus reproduce the following code.

```
    INSERT INTO `actions` (`aid`, `type`, `callback`, `parameters`, `description`) VALUES
    ('5', 'system', 'views_bulk_operations_script_action', 'a:1:{s:6:"script";s:452:"$string = $object->field_ruling_content[0][''value''];\r\n// do replacements\r\n$search = array(\r\n ''<h4>Membres</h4>'', \r\n ''<h4>Membre</h4>'',\r\n ''<h2><strong>Membres</strong></h2>'',\r\n ''<h2><strong>Membre</strong></h2>'',\r\n);\r\n$replace = array(\r\n ''<h2>Membres</h2>'',\r\n ''<h2>Membre</h2>'',\r\n ''<h2>Membres</h2>'',\r\n ''<h2>Membre</h2>'',\r\n );\r\n$string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);\r\n$object->field_ruling_content[0][''value''] = $string;\r\nnode_save($object);";}', 'Cleanup');
```

The only bit that gets me confused is this `a:1:{s:6:"script";s:452:"`. I tried looking up `a:1:`, `s:6:` and `s:452:` on google, but it didn't quite get me the results I was looking for. What are they and what do they mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a [serialized](http://php.net/serialize) representation of PHP variables. You can decode it by running it through [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize).

The syntax is fairly simple once you understand what it's doing. `s:6:"script"` means "string, six characters, contents 'script'".